# how to change the date format as it not the same with the database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

As the coding show at textbox 18/02/2012 (for example). but in database it is 02/18/2012.

```
TxtReqDate.Text = Calendar.SelectionStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")        
cboTermCode.Focus()
Calendar.Visible = False
```

But when i want to retrieve the related data for the date using coding below :

```
sqlCbo2 = "SELECT DISTINCT gear_code FROM gear WHERE est_start_date='" & TxtReqDate.Text & "'"
```

it say invalid date.
i cannot change the date format in the database.

if i change the code TxtReqDate.Text = Calendar.SelectionStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") TO TxtReqDate.Text = Calendar.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString as it will appear 02/18/2012 at the textbox the data will appear but i want 18/02/2012 to appear at the textbox.

Comment: Not only should you use parameterized queries to avoid Bobby Tables, you should also use them so that you're not using database-side functions to format your arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to parse that data and transform it into a Date value.

Use it like this (correct any syntactical error):

> where do i should put it. example??

```
sqlCbo2 = "SELECT DISTINCT gear_code FROM gear WHERE est_start_date=STR_TO_DATE('" & TxtReqDate.Text & "','%d/%m/%Y')"
```

Comment: where do i should put it. example??

Comment: Routine (str_to_date) can not be resolved. i get this error message.

Comment: It is a mysql function, nothing to do with vb

Comment: i get the idea but im developing it for vb.

Answer (score 0):

This example is actually using the `OleDbCommand` but the syntax is similar for the `SqlCommand`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

```
Dim comm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(reportQueryString, conn)

comm.Parameters.Add("[ReportDate]", OleDbType.Date)

comm.Parameters("[ReportDate]").Value = dateVariable
```

You can see that when you add the parameter, you specify the dataType the command should convert your data type to. This way you're not doing raw string manipulation yourself.

Comment: im using odbc as i know it is similar.